# WHMCS Permissions Error

Tags: php, permissions, chmod, whmcs, 777

I currently have a WHMCS configuration. I have the following folders (crons, downloads, attachments, and templates_c), located in a separate directory than the WHMCS installation. I have the correct path labeled in the configuration.php and the permissions for the folders are correct. I am getting this error: The templates compiling directory '"directory"' must be writeable (CHMOD 777) before you can continue. The templates_c directory is set to CHMOD 777 as it states, but it still doesn't work.

Directory for this folder:
/var/www/WHMCS Private/

Directory of WHMCS installation:
/var/www/html/supertolerator.com/hosting/billing

Configuration.php:
$templates_compiledir = '/var/www/WHMCS Private/templates_c/'; (This is the line telling WHMCS where to look for that folder.)

I have tried contacting WHMCS but they were no help and told me to ask my hosting provider. Can't do that as my server is self-managed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the private-root to a non-escaped folder name.
If that does not work for you, try to execute `chmod -R 777 templates_c` that is recursive and would also set the permissions of the subfolders and files.

As you use that location in your compiled, you will have to use the escape character `\` so that it can see the space.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, it could possibly be a bug caused of the blank space in your directory name "WHMCD Private"? Try with lowercase and without blanks space.

Have you tried the permissions your self? su to the webserver user (eg apache/httpd or similar) and then try to create a file in the templates_c directory:

```
touch /var/www/WHMCS Private/templates_c/
```

If you get a permission error it's still a server issue, otherwise it could be whmcs related.

Answer (score 0):

The directory should be something like the below:

`/home/username/public_html/whmcs directory/templates_c/`

**username**: your cpanel username

**whmcs directory**: your whmcs folder name